# Get "An item with the same key has already been added" when install SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, installation

I tried to install SQL Server 2019 but I keep getting the error "An item with the same key has already been added."

My installer summary log like that

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2147024809
  Exit facility code:            7
  Exit error code:               87
  Exit message:                  An item with the same key has already been added.
  Start time:                    2022-01-14 15:24:06
  End time:                      2022-01-14 15:35:25
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.2000.5&EvtType=0x51E5756F%400x294A9FD9&EvtType=0x51E5756F%400x294A9FD9

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  TRUONGNN-NEW
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19043)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       15
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\SQLServer\ExpressAdv_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

Azul OpenJDK JRE installed. For information on Azul Zulu OpenJDK third party licensing, see https://www.azul.com/licenses-zulu-third-party-licenses/

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, ADVANCEDANALYTICS, SQL_INST_MR, SQL_INST_MPY, SQL_INST_JAVA, FULLTEXT, CONN, BC, SDK, SNAC_SDK
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$SQLEXPRESS
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     true
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      true
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Japanese_CI_AS
  SQLJAVADIR:                    
  SQLMAXDOP:                     0
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           ALLEXCEED\truongnn
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220114_152405\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Warning    IsFirewallEnabled                The Windows Firewall is enabled. Make sure the appropriate ports are open to enable remote access. See the rules documentation at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094702 for information about ports to open for each feature.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220114_152405\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: System.ArgumentException
    Message: 
        An item with the same key has already been added.
    HResult : 0x80070057
    Data: 
      HelpLink.EvtType = 0x51E5756F@0x294A9FD9
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
        at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.ConfigExtension.AddFeatureNotificationHandlerInstallActionMetadataHandler.PackageActionScheduledEventHandler(Object sender, PackageInstallActionMetadataCreatedEventArgs eventArgs)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.NotificationHandler.Invoke(Object notification, Object[] objectArray)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.NotificationService.OnNotify(Object eventKey, Object notification, Object[] objectArray)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallScheduler.OnPackageInstallActionMetadataCreated(PackageId pkgId, WorkflowObject workflowData, ActionKey actionKey, ActionMetadata actionMd, PackageInstallAction pkgInstallAction)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallScheduler.CreatePackageInstallActionForPackage(ActionKey pkgActionKey, PackageId pkg, InstallModificationMutatorStore pkgActionModifiers, InstallAction pkgAction, WorkflowObject packageInstallWorkflow)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallScheduler.CreateInstallActionsForPackage(String actionKeyTemplate, PackageInstallModificationModifier installActionModifier, PackageId pkg, WorkflowObject packageInstallWorkflow)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallScheduler.SchedulePackages(ICollection`1 packages, PackageInstallModificationModifier installActionModifier, WorkflowObject packageInstallWorkflow)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.SchedulePackageInstallActionsAction.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__0()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
```

What I've tried so far is trying to find anything related to SQL Server and uninstall or delete them as much as I can, then try to install SQL Server again, but it still had the same error.

Is there any way to fix this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by installing other versions of SQL Server.

In my case, I installed SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Does that mean you installed SQL Server 2017 and upgraded it to SQL Server 2019?
Was it tried with Developer Edition or a Licensed Version? I tried to upgrade my 2017 Developer Edition to Licensed Version and since it failed with some other reason, I tried to upgrade to Developer Edition 2019 and got with this error.